# How to get the different sizes of part files at reducer output in map reduce programmer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How to get the different sizes of part files at reducer output in map reduce programmer.

Eg. If I want to have 2 part file at reducer side with different size how can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure if you can change the number of output files on the basis of size, but 2 part files can be done using `job.setNumReduceTasks(2)`

Comment: It really isn't clear from your question what you want to know. I would have a go at clarifying it.